# Magento Error: SELECT e.entity_id, e.type_id, e.attribute_set_id, etc

Tags: magento

I'm all of sudden getting the following error

> THERE HAS BEEN AN ERROR PROCESSING YOUR REQUEST
>   EXCEPTION PRINTING IS DISABLED BY DEFAULT FOR SECURITY REASONS.
>
> ERROR LOG RECORD NUMBER: 1902398614

I had checked up the error log in var/report. I got the following details

```
a:5:{i:0;s:1772:"SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `t_compare`.`product_id`, `t_compare`.`customer_id`, `t_compare`.`visitor_id`, `t_compare`.`store_id` AS `item_store_id`, `t_compare`.`catalog_compare_item_id`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `cat_index`.`visibility`, `store_cat_index`.`visibility` AS `store_visibility`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `cat_index`.`visibility`, `e`.`name` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`
```

I can however access my backend but get the above result in the frontend.

I'm using magento 1.9.

Comment: Have you [searched for the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PRINTING+IS+DISABLED+BY+DEFAULT+FOR+SECURITY+REASONS)?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure if you are not using any custom query where flat table is directly used. If its the case just try to reindex magento properly it will be fixed.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for replying. I had uninstalled all the recent extensions and the changes i made and was able to get back the site.

Comment: Please make the Question Solved